# Convert to-and-from a local coordinate system relative to a n-sided polygon

Tags: coordinate-systems, interpolation, polygons, finite-element-method, barycentric-coordinates

## Question

Let $P$ be a convex, regular $N$-sided 2D polygon; take for instance, a pentagon.

Let $T$ be a point located within $P$, or alongside any of its sides.

##### Is it possible to convert $T$'s cartesian coordinates into an alternate coordinate system, such that the resulting N-length vector acts as a local coordinate system relative to $P$ sides/vertexes, referring to back to $T$?

## And if so, how to convert to and from such coordinate system?

Any help on the subject it's welcome; ranging from examples, alternative suggestions and explicit answers, to guidance on places where to look for more information.

---

### Edits

## #1

After some research, I found there are a few existing methods for doing so (`Wachspress coordinates`, `Mean Value coordinates`, `Harmonic coordinates`...), but I haven't been able to find any information at all about the concepts behind them, or any (simple) examples to guide myself on.

Based on what I've read so far, `Wachspress coordinates` look adequate to accomplish my objective; however, should any other ideas be brought to the table, as long as it serves its purpose to allow me to accomplish my objective, I'm fine with it.

Comment: About Wachspress and mean value coordinates, an excellent document exists [here](https://www.mn.uio.no/math/english/people/aca/michaelf/papers/wach_mv.pdf)

Comment: I greatly appreciate your contribution: Do you, by any chance, know where can I find any examples on the application of these coordinates? Looking through the steps of an example would significantly help me understand better the concepts involved.

Comment: I just know they are used by people in the domain of "Image synthesis", which is a keyword you can use in a google search. I am more familiar with barycentric/trilinear coordinates (see for example http://journal-1.eu/2015/01/Francisco-Javier-Barycentric-Coordinates-pp.32-48.pdf)